# How to include attributes in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to include the original attributes in the model along with the count

```js
const tickers = async (ctx) => {
    let data = await ReadSchema.aggregate([
     { "$project": { "tickers.symbol": 1 }},
     { "$unwind": "$tickers" },
     { "$group": { "_id": "$tickers.symbol", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}},
      //  {
      //  "$addFields": {
      //     exchange: "$tickers.exchange",
      //     name: "$tickers.name",
      //     symbol: "$tickers.symbol",
      //   },
      // },
     { $sort: { "count": -1 }},
    ]);

    ctx.body = data;
};
```

Here is the schema:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ReadSchema = new Schema(
  {
    tickers: [{ name: 'String', symbol: 'String', exchange: 'String' }],
  },
  { timestamps: true },
);
```

I'm only getting `_id` and `count` in output...I want `symbol`, `name` and `exchange` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Fixes,

- `{ "$project": { "tickers.symbol": 1 }},` after this stage the pipeline have only `symbol` field, you can't access other fields (name, exchange) in below stages like group, so just change this stage to

```
{ "$project": { "tickers": 1 } },
```

- You need to pass that fields in `$group` stage using [$frist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or either [$last](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) operators,

```
{ 
  "$group": { 
    "_id": "$tickers.symbol", 
    "count": { "$sum": 1 },
    "exchange": { "$first": "$tickers.exchange" },
    "name": { "$first": "$tickers.name" }
  }
}
```

---

Your final query would be:

```
const tickers = async (ctx) => {
    let data = await ReadSchema.aggregate([
        { "$project": { "tickers": 1 } },
        { "$unwind": "$tickers" },
        { 
            "$group": { 
                "_id": "$tickers.symbol", 
                "count": { "$sum": 1 },
                "exchange": { "$first": "$tickers.exchange" },
                "name": { "$first": "$tickers.name" }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "symbol": "$_id",
                "exchange": 1,
                "name": 1,
                "count": 1
            }
        },
        { $sort: { "count": -1 } }
    ]);
    ctx.body = data;
};
```